# Change schema of exception_handler gem table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exceptionhandler

I have installed the [exception_handler gem](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) and am storing exceptions in the `errors` table.

I am attempting to add additional information to this table. However, this table is created a the `exception_handler` migrations and not my apps. `exception_handler` migrations run AFTER my migrations, so when I attempt to modify the table, the table does not exist.

How can I add additional information to this `errors` table?

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to look at the other generators with `rails -T | grep exception_handler`. This yielded the generator `rails exception_handler:install:migrations` (which I could not find in the documentation).

**Update:**
Turns out installing these migrations is deprecated as does not solve the problem. I am still unable to modify the schema in any way.